# Adding items to Dictionary without using Add method in C#

Tags: c#, dictionary

I have items and I want to add them to Dictionary Without using Add method (because it consumes number of lines). Is there any way to add items to Dictionary like

```
new List<string>() { "P","J","K","L","M" };
```

or like AddRange Method in List. Any help will be highly appericiated.

Comment: How come you don't want more lines?

Comment: If it is not for initialization, you can simply use **dictionaryObject[key] = value;**.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referenced from [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb531208.aspx)

```
 Dictionary<int, StudentName> students = new Dictionary<int, StudentName>()
 {
   { 111, new StudentName {FirstName="Sachin", LastName="Karnik", ID=211}},
   { 112, new StudentName {FirstName="Dina", LastName="Salimzianova", ID=317}},
   { 113, new StudentName {FirstName="Andy", LastName="Ruth", ID=198}}
};
```

Answer (score 3):

You can easily create an extension method that does an AddRange for your dictionary

```
namespace System.Collections.Generic
{
    public static class DicExt
    {
        public static void AddRange<K, V>(this Dictionary<K, V> dic, IEnumerable<K> keys, V v)
        {
            foreach (var k in keys)
                dic[k] = v;
        }
    }
}

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {

            var list  = new List<string>() { "P", "J", "K", "L", "M" };
            var dic = new Dictionary<string, bool>();

            dic.AddRange(list, true);


            Console.Read();

        }
    }
}
```

Comment: @ethicallogics From your question it wasn't clear whether you meant initialization

Answer (score 3):

it's as easy as

```
var dictionary = new Dictionary<int, string>() {{1, "firstString"},{2,"secondString"}};
```